# Triggering ajaxStart() onclick on a button

Tags: jquery, ajax

I am trying to trigger ajaxstart() when a button with a class is clicked however it's not working, any feedback would be appreciated.

Thanks.

Code:

```
    $('.search-btn').ajaxStart(function () {
        $('#spinner').show();
    }).ajaxComplete(function () {
        $('#spinner').hide();
    });
```

Comment: `ajaxstart()` shouldn't be "triggered when a button is clicked" - it should be defined on load and then will automatically trigger when you run an ajax task.  If you also want the *same* functionality (spinner show/hide) when clicking a button, then put the functionality in a function and call from both.

Answer (score 1):

`$.ajaxStart()` and `$.ajaxComplete()` should be attached to `$(document)`. See [`$.ajaxStart()`](http://api.jquery.com/ajaxStart/)

> As of jQuery 1.9, all the handlers for the [jQuery global Ajax
>   events](http://api.jquery.com/category/ajax/global-ajax-event-handlers/), including those added with the `.ajaxStart()` method, *must*
>   be attached to `document`.

```
    $(document).ajaxStart(function () {
        $("#spinner").show();
    }).ajaxComplete(function () {
        $("#spinner").hide();
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Bit confused as to what is happening in your example. But I've written out what I **think** you want to do.

```
$('.search-btn').on('click', function () {
    $(this).ajaxStart(function(){
        $('#spinner').show();
    }).ajaxComplete(function () {
        $('#spinner').hide();
    });
});
```

Comment: "trigger" ajax start, not setup ajaxstart - this won't show the spinner on click.   If this really *is* what the OP wants, then they need a slap. :)

Comment: Agreed, not entirely sure what they are after, my answer is probably not useful in the slightest. :P